# How to make contenteditable to child element using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a set of html codes with a class of `nitssection`, I'm displaying the buttons `onclick` event of `JQuery`, I've some text under it, I'm trying to make it `contenteditable` `onclick` event, but I guess the `nitssection` click event is not making it true. As I can see `.nitssection` event is working, on clicking I can see my buttons. Like for example my HTML code looks like:

```
<div class="section nitssection" data-nitsid="3">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="box-content">
                    <h4 class="box-title nitstext"><a href="text.html">Some text</a></h4>
                    <p class="nitstext">Paragraph</p>
                    <a href="text.html" class="btn btn-sm style4 hover-blue">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

for displaying buttons I've:

```
$('.nitssection').click(function(e) {
    $('#' + nitsid).css({
        //Displaying buttons
    }).fadeIn(400);
    $(this).click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
});
```

For making `nitstext` class as contenteditable, I'm tyring:

```
$('.nitssection').find('a').each(fucntion () {
     $(this).removeAttr("href");
});
$('.nitstext').click(function () {
   $(this).attr("contenteditable", "true");
});
```

I'm not able to achieve this. Help me out.

Comment: Why are you hooking up a **new** event handler every time `.nitsection` is clicked?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm having a buttons which is sortable handle of the `nitssection` which is displayed on click event of that, I want to edit few text which present inside  `nitstext` which is present inside the section.

Comment: That does mean it makes sense to add a new click element to the `.nitsection` element every time it's clicked, which is what the above does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the element exists, `contenteditable` is a property (but your `attr` should work anyway, any value technically makes boolean attributes true).

I think it's making it editable, but it's not obvious because it doesn't seem to gain focus; adding a call to `.focus` after steting it editable seems to make that work. Also, you have `fucntion` instead of `function` which is preventing part of your code running.

So I'd make the `prop` change and add `.focus` and fix the typo:

```
$('.nitstext').click(function () {
   $(this).prop("contenteditable", true).focus();
   //      ^^^^                    ^^^^ ^^^^^^^^
});
```

...which seems to work *(I commented out the code using the `nitsid` variable, as I don't have one)*:

```js
$('.nitssection').click(function(e) {
  /*
    $('#' + nitsid).css({
        //Displaying buttons
    }).fadeIn(400);
  */
    $(this).click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});

$('.nitssection').find('a').each(function () {
     $(this).removeAttr("href");
});
$('.nitstext').click(function () {
   $(this).prop("contenteditable", true).focus();
});
```

```html
<div class="section nitssection" data-nitsid="3">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="box-content">
                    <h4 class="box-title nitstext"><a href="text.html">Some text</a></h4>
                    <p class="nitstext">Paragraph</p>
                    <a href="text.html" class="btn btn-sm style4 hover-blue">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: This code is highly suspect:

```
$('.nitssection').click(function(e) {
    $('#' + nitsid).css({
        //Displaying buttons
    }).fadeIn(400);
    $(this).click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
});
```

It's setting up a click handler on all `.nitsection` elements and, when they're clicked, adding **another** click handler on that specific `.nitsection` element. Every click will add a further one. That doesn't doesn't make any sense.

You've said this is to stop clicks on `.nitstext` from firing the `.nitssection` handler; instead of doing it that way, do this in the `.nitstext` handler:

```
$('.nitstext').click(function (e) {
   // -------------------------^
   $(this).prop("contenteditable", true).focus();
   e.stopPropagation(); // <===
});
```

Comment: So according to you I must place a :not selector, I mean `$('.nitssection :not('.nitstext')').click();` like this?

Comment: @NitishKumar: What's the goal? To prevent a click on `.nitstext` triggering the event handler on `.nitssection`? Just stop propagation in the `.nitstext` click handler.

Comment: To stop propagation.

Comment: @NitishKumar: Just put it in the `.nitstext` click handler. `return false` will work (it both stops propagation and prevents the default action, but there's no default action for a paragraph click, so...). Or accept the argument as `e` and use `e.stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score 1):

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/q8yax2t5/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="section nitssection" data-nitsid="3">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="box-content">
                    <h4 class="box-title nitstext"><a href="text.html">Some text</a></h4>
                    <p class="nitstext">Paragraph</p>
                    <a href="text.html" class="btn btn-sm style4 hover-blue">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.nitssection').find('a').each(function () {
    $(this).removeAttr("href");
});

$(document).on('click', '.nitstext', function() {
  this.contentEditable = true;
  $(this).focus();
});
```